# How to get particular items from website in C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I dont have API of website, but I want to retreive some informations from it.
They look like this:

Name, Vocation and Level.

To achieve that I followed [Microsoft C# Make Get Request](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-PL/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/development/make-get-request) and right now I've got full informations from [Website](https://tibiantis.online/?page=whoisonline)

From this point I decided to find table:

```
if (sLine.StartsWith("<table width="))
    {
      Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Right now I've got whole table with names, levels etc. But its all in one line...
Data right now looks like this: (but there is much more records in it)

```
<table width="100%" class="tabi"><tr><td colspan=7>Characters</td></tr> <tr><td height='30' style='background-color:#9f8f6d;'><a href=?page=whoisonline&ord=name&sort=DESC&id=1>&#8593;Name</a></td><td width='240' style='background-color:#9f8f6d;'><a href=?page=whoisonline&ord=voc&sort=DESC&id=1>Vocation</a></td><td width='120' style='background-color:#9f8f6d;'><a href=?page=whoisonline&ord=lvl&sort=DESC&id=1>Level</a></td></tr><tr class='hover'> <td><a href='?page=character&name=Abe' class='menulink_hs'>Abe</a></td> <td>Elder Druid</td> <td>19</td> </tr></table><br />
```

so I started trimming it like this:

```
if (sLine.StartsWith("<table width="))
                        {
                            foreach (var a in sLine.Split("<td>"))
                            {
                                var replacementToken = "";
                                foreach (var b in a.Split("</td>"))
                                {
                                    foreach (var c in b.Split("</tr>"))
                                    {
                                        foreach (var d in c.Split("<tr class='hover'>"))
                                        {
                                            foreach (var f in d.Split("</a>"))
                                            {
                                                string g = f.Replace("'", replacementToken)
                                                    .Replace("?", replacementToken)
                                                    .Replace("class=menulink_hs", replacementToken)
                                                    .Replace("a href", replacementToken)
                                                    .Replace("=page=character&", replacementToken);
                                                //f.TrimStart('>');
                                                //f.Trim('>');
                                                listBox1.Items.Add(g);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

and I believe there is a better solution than xxxxx foreach loops.
**What is the best way to get data from this table?**

My full code:

```
string sURL;
                sURL = "https://tibiantis.online/?page=whoisonline";

                WebRequest wrGETURL;
                wrGETURL = WebRequest.Create(sURL);

                WebProxy myProxy = new WebProxy("myproxy", 80);
                myProxy.BypassProxyOnLocal = true;

                Stream objStream;
                objStream = wrGETURL.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();

                StreamReader objReader = new StreamReader(objStream);

                string sLine = "";
                int i = 0;

                while (sLine != null)
                {
                    i++;
                    sLine = objReader.ReadLine();
                    if (sLine != null)
                    {
                        if (sLine.StartsWith("<table width="))
                        {
                            foreach (var a in sLine.Split("<td>"))
                            {
                                var replacementToken = "";
                                foreach (var b in a.Split("</td>"))
                                {
                                    foreach (var c in b.Split("</tr>"))
                                    {
                                        foreach (var d in c.Split("<tr class='hover'>"))
                                        {
                                            foreach (var f in d.Split("</a>"))
                                            {
                                                string g = f.Replace("'", replacementToken)
                                                    .Replace("?", replacementToken)
                                                    .Replace("class=menulink_hs",replacementToken)
                                                    .Replace("a href", replacementToken)
                                                    .Replace("=page=character&",replacementToken);
                                                //f.TrimStart('>');
                                                //f.Trim('>');
                                                listBox1.Items.Add(g);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
```

Comment: Try [html agility pack](https://html-agility-pack.net).

Comment: Or [Angle Sharp](https://anglesharp.github.io/)